# submitting form data on a specific bootstrap wizard step

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, wizard

Ive created a bootstrap wizard with several steps.  When a user clicks the 'save & continue' button on the second wizard step, I want to commit the form data entered to the underlying data store before moving to the third step.  I cant seem to get the form submission to work, the actionmethod on the controller isnt being called.  This is the javascript on the page, it is being hit, but the controller action isnt

```js
$("#scheduleReport").on("click", function () {
            // Get the record's ID via attribute
            //var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            $('#frmAddSchedule').validate();
            $('#frmAddSchedule').submit();
        });

        $('#frmAddSchedule').on('submit', function (e) {
            var $form = $(e.target);
            if ($form.valid()) {

                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Create", "ReportScheduler")',
                    data: $form.serialize(),
                    async: true,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (returnval) {
                        if (returnval.success == true) {
                            
                            $("#schedulerGrid").igGrid("dataBind");
                        }
                        if (returnval.success == false) {
                            //$form.parents('.bootbox').modal('hide');
                            bootbox.alert({ title: '<div class="text-center text-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ERROR</div>', message: returnval['responseText'] });
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (returnval) {
                        //$form.parents('.bootbox').modal('hide');
                        bootbox.alert(returnval['responseText']);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

and the controller action method

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Prefix = "Schedule")]ReportScheduleViewModel item)
    {
```

are there any 'best practices' for doing this ?  what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as a start I can maybe help you with the part of beeing able to call the controller action. As for the question "best practices", you gave to little details.

So:

```
/**
 * On document ready.
 * 
 * @return void
 */
$(document).ready(function () {
    activateScheduleReport();
    activateAddScheduleFormSubmit();
});

/**
 * Activate schedule report click event.
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function activateScheduleReport() {
    $("#scheduleReport").on("click", function () {
        // Get the record's ID via attribute
        //var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        validateAddScheduleForm();
        submitAddScheduleForm();
    });
}

/**
 * Activate add schedule form submit.
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function activateAddScheduleFormSubmit() {
    $('#frmAddSchedule').submit(function (e) {
        var $form = $(this);

        var ajax = $.ajax({
            async: true, // Please don't use this! :-)
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '@Url.Action("Create", "ReportScheduler")',
            data: $form.serialize()
        });
        ajax.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (response.success) {
                $("#schedulerGrid").igGrid("dataBind");
            } else {
                //$form.parents('.bootbox').modal('hide');
                bootbox.alert({
                    title: '<div class="text-center text-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ERROR</div>',
                    message: response.responseText
                });
            }
        });
        ajax.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //$form.parents('.bootbox').modal('hide');
            bootbox.alert(textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
        });
        ajax.always(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // Do whatever you want here...
        });

        // Use this to prevent page refreshing. No need for preventDefault().
        return false;
    });
}

/**
 * Validate add schedule form.
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function validateAddScheduleForm() {
    $('#frmAddSchedule').validate();
}

/**
 * Submit add schedule form.
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function submitAddScheduleForm() {
    $('#frmAddSchedule').submit();
}
```

In the action you should use:

```
echo json_encode('whatever response string');
```

or

```
echo json_encode(array(responseText: 'whatever response string'));
```

**Nota bene:**

- I used `dataType: json`. You can also use `dataType: html`. If, then
  echo the string or the array without the `json_encode`.
- I renamed your `returnval` to `response`.
- Watch the parameters of ajax `fail()`, e.g of the old `error()`.
- I structured the js code in functions.
- As I come from the PHP world I used `echo` to print and `json_encode` to encode in the JSON format.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried your code but it didnt work, the controller action still isnt being hit (mvc & c#), also what do you mean by this  async: true, // Please don't use this! :-)

Comment: When you are using "async: false", each time you're sending an ajax request your browser freezes, waiting for it to finish. AJAX is by definition an asynchronous call and shoul remain like this.

Comment: @proteus Are you sure that the `url: '@Url.Action("Create", "ReportScheduler")'`is correct?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the isue in the end, the wizard example I used already had a form element inside it (hadnt noticed it) which I had wrapped in my own form which was stopping the form submiting.  It works fine now